# I need an advice concerning timers in c#?

Tags: c#, timer

I am setting up a library system using c#, this system consists on the following:

Students can book books remotely but this booking operation is only valid for 24h, If the member does not show up within that time limit, the book is automatically released and if they repeat this for 3 times they get banned for 15 days.

For this I started setting up a timer (using System.Threading.Timer) but I need a timer each time a student books a certain book and I am really stuck on how to do this. I have this idea of creating a List of Timers and each time a booking operation occurs I create a timer and I put it in the list.

```
    private List<Timer> timerList;
    private void SetUpTimer(TimeSpan alertTime)
    {
        DateTime current = DateTime.Now;
        TimeSpan timeLeft = alertTime - current.TimeOfDay;
        Timer timer = new System.Threading.Timer(x =>
        {
            this.doWork();
        }, null, timeLeft, Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan);
     timerList.Add(timer);
     }

    private void doWork()
    {
    }
```

so is this a good way to implement the idea?

is there any better idea to implement this?

Edit 1: I used a database to put all of the info and a timestamp each time a book is booked.

Comment: You're going to create a list of timers? What happens if your program crashes? Oops, there goes your system. No, this doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: yea that's why I am asking about some advice I don't really know how to set this

Comment: Use a DateTime to record when a book is.. booked. Storage of this information is separate for establishing timers / processing to “do an action” after expiration. Usually some form of database is used to persist the information. A timer might then be used, while the service is running, to send reminder alerts (or whatever is required). A prudent design would allow reconciliation of state with minimal or non-overlapping updates.

Comment: Well clearly you can't trust a program to be running and functioning all the time. Programs crash, or go down for updates, or the server gets rebooted. So you have to store the booking information outside of the memory of the application. This usually means the database. Then you can have something that checks the database every so often, and processes the records that are older than 24 hours.

Comment: You don't need timers for this at all. You don't even need to check periodically... Just store the booking date/time for every booked book. Whenever somebody else wants to book a book, check if the book has already a booking date/time stored. If not, the book is not booked already. If it has a booking date/time, check if that date/time is too old (i.e., older than 24h). If so remove the outdated booking information and treat the book as not booked already. If the booking date/time is not too old, keep treating the book as already booked.

Comment: @mason I thought about creating a single timer that checks every so often but what I want to make is exactly after the time limit has passed the book is cleared because maybe at that exact time another student wanted to book that same book or something.

Comment: You need to decide what "exact time" means. If there's a 5 seconds delay, is that acceptable? What about 30 seconds? I haven't been to a library in years, are books really in that high of a demand that a 1 minute delay is unacceptable? Anyways, decide how much delay is acceptable, then figure out if having a single timer check the system every so often is good enough.

Comment: @mason as I said the book is automatically released if the borrower didn't present himself at the library within 24h and if they repeat this for 3 times they get banned for 15 days for this purpose the time limit was put.

Comment: "_if they repeat this for 3 times_" That's a bit how-ya-doin'... Such a rule would need to be more precisely qualified to be fair and just. After all, doing 3x booking without pickup in the span of two years is rather quite different from doing the same within only one month or even one week, no?

Comment: @elgonzo yea I agree but I am just doing a university project regarding this and that rule was one of the tasks they asked us to do, also thanks for telling me I didn't quite think about that, I will implement it as you said (doing 3x booking without pickup in the span of one month)

Comment: thank you all for your help ^^

Comment: By the way, if your project/system needs to enact a ban as you mentioned, my suggestion of not needing periodic checks (or timers) doesn't apply anymore, as you now would need to check periodically to see whether the ban hammer needs to be swung ;-)

Comment: yea thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a windows service

   - [Create a Windows service application in Visual Studio | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/walkthrough-creating-a-windows-service-application-in-the-component-designer)
2. the service  will query the database every 1m and update the booking table

   ```
                                 +----------------------+
                                 |                      |
                                 |                      |
                                 |    +---------+       |
   +-------------+         book  |    |         |       |
   |             +----------------->  |  Data   |       |
   |   User      |               |    |  Base   |       |
   |             |               |    |         |       |
   +-------------+               |    +-----+---+       |
                                 |          ^           |
                                 |          | check     |
                                 |     +----+----+      |
                                 |     |         |      |
                                 |     |         |      |
                                 |     | Windows |      |
                                 |     | Service |      |
                                 |     |         |      |
                                 |     +---------+      |
                                 |                      |
                                 |                      |
                                 |                      |
                                 +----------------------+

                                        server
   ```

Comment: I think this helps a lot the best idea to get yet thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment:(

I think as others mentioned, that's not a good design. It is better to be event driven. aka. When checking if a book is available, decide weather it is locked by someone within 24 hrs.

i.e.

User A could lock a book 1, and you could save this information somewhere with, as metioned by user2864740, a timestamp (in C# DateTime). For example:
book 1: 2019-01-05 15:00

Later, 4 things could happen:
1. the borrower came on time
2. the borrower came late
3. someone came earlier and try to check this book out
4. someone came 24 hr later and try to check this book out

Each one could be considered an event.

The idea here is very general in software: don't call me (with information I may/may not need), I'll call you when needed.

Hope this helps.

So if you are develp some management system, it is better to start with a database. If just a after class excercise, you could even use the file system, checkout how to use IO related classes in C#.

Have fun!

Comment: thank you for your answer I did use a database and I used the timestamp thing, but what if the borrower didn't come at all and after that he did the same thing later, that's why I added the banning system after doing this for 3 times they get banned for 15 days.

Comment: I believe you could easily record that in another table.
e.x. the 2nd time when he comes, you put a record like:
User 1-book1-1 failure get
And when failure get reach a threshold, you ban him from locking the book again. You could do the check before each lock atempts, and checking against the failure count. And don't forget to clear it once he really checks out the book.

Comment: oh yea that's a good way to put it, thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to rethink your problem and solution.
What if a student make a reservation on multiple items, lets say 5, on the same day and never comes for getting them. Should the system ban the person for not collecting his 5 items? Or should they count as 1 reservation?

For the solution I will suggest a model where the item is booked for the rest of the day + 24 hours. Then you can add the reservation to a table in your database and remove them when the students collecting their items. In this case you can check your reservation table only once a day and take ban students if needed.